# UIWebView showing the URL instead of webpage

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xcode4

I try to load a URL(in string format) to a UIWebView, but instead of showing the webpage, it shows the URL. Here's my code:

```
URL = @"www.Google.com" 
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]; 
baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[webView clearsContextBeforeDrawing];   
[webView loadHTMLString:URL baseURL:baseURL];
[webView setNeedsLayout];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadHTMLString:baseURL:` takes the html page content as input and not just URL in string form. It treats `www.Google.com` as a html string and it gets shown. You will have to do,

```
NSString * htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: `baseURL` should be `nil` in this case.

Comment: what should I put as the baseURL?

Comment: Are you doing this after the webview is added to the view hierarchy?

Comment: What you mean by that? Actually I'm trying to create an apps that will launch a webpage when the button is pressed, I get all the things done, only left this UIWebView which didn't show me anything.

Comment: You can look at this [`sample`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/Webber.zip)(This works!) and see how it is different.

Answer (score 1):

You have loaded the content of the UIWebView with the string 'www.Google.com' not the content from that address. loadHTMLString will load HTML content from a string.

You need to use loadRequest.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `loadRequest` instead for www.Google.com

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```